# de Rham cohomology on $\mathbb R^n$ is equal to $\{0 \}$ for $k>0$, $\mathbb R$ for $k=0$.

Tags: differential-forms, de-rham-cohomology

Let $\Omega^k (U)$ be a set of $k-$ diffrential form on $U$, where $U \subset \mathbb R^n$ is region, and define
$
Z^k (U)$ be a set of $k-$ closed form, $B^k (U)$ be a set of $k-$ exact form.

Then, de Rham cohomology $H^k (U)$ is defined as $H^k (U)=Z^k (U) / B^k (U)$.

I want to show $H^k (\mathbb R^n)=
\begin{cases}
\{0 \} \ &(k>0)\\
 \ \mathbb R \ &(k=0)\\
\end{cases}
$

---

Here is what I did so far.

For $k>0,$ $B^k(\mathbb R^n)=Z^k (\mathbb R^n)$ (Poincare's Lenma) thus $H^k(\mathbb R^n)=Z^k(\mathbb R^n)/ Z^k (\mathbb R^n)=\{ Z^k (\mathbb R^n) \}.$

For $k=0,$ I have $B^0 (\mathbb R^n)=\{ 0\},$
\begin{align*}
H^0 (\mathbb R^n)&=\{ [\omega] \mid \omega \in Z^0 (U) \} \\
&=\{ [f] \mid f \in C^\infty (U), df=0 \}\\
&=\{ [c] \mid c\in \mathbb R \}
\end{align*} where $[ \cdot ]$ is an equivalent class with $\omega \sim \omega' \iff \omega-\omega'\in B^k (U)$.

So, my question is

(i) Why $\{ Z^k (\mathbb R^n) \}=\{0 \}$ for $k>0$ ?

(ii) Why $\{ [c] \mid c\in \mathbb R \}=\mathbb R$ ?

I'd like you to give me any help for understandng this.

Comment: This is really just linear algebra. $H^k$ is a finite-dimensional real vector space, and such a space is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^d$. For your first question, you have a quotient $H^k = V/V \cong \mathbb{R}^0 = \{0\}$. And for your second question, you have a 1-dimensional $V$ and $H^k = V/\{0\} \cong \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Alex was faster. :P

Comment: So, is the statement not $H^k (\mathbb R^n)=
\begin{cases}
\{0 \} \\
 \ \mathbb R \\
\end{cases}
$ but $H^k (\mathbb R^n) \color{red}\cong
\begin{cases}
\{0 \} \\
 \ \mathbb R \\
\end{cases}
$ ?